# iPhone scroll UITableview by swiping out side the table view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

In my case I have UIView and UITableView controller. What I want is to scroll the table view by swiping the UIView. I have added swipe up and swipe down gestures for the UIView. When I swipe on this view, scroll the table view along the direction of swipe. Is it posible?

Comment: yes, an easy way is to use the UITableView as a normal UIScrollView (UITableView is a UIScrollView, inherits from that class, so you can use all the UIScrollView methods for it, and relative protocol methods too)

Comment: @meronix: thanks for you quick replay. cold you please post some sample codes?

Comment: @Muhammad: UIView isn't a sub class of UITableview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call this method from your viewDidLoad.
This method will disable the scrolling of the tableview to prevent manual scrolling.Assuming that you have 100 rows of height 30 and myview is the view on which have to perform the scrolling. Swipe gestures are added on myview,it is important to set the direction of the swipe

-(void)initialSetup
{

```
[self.tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];  
int numberOfRows=100;
int rowHeight=30;
myview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(280, 0, 30, numberOfRows*rowHeight)];
[myview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[self.view addSubview:myview];
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDown=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(motion:)];
[swipeDown setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown];
[myview addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(motion:)];
[swipeUp setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];
[myview addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];}
```

The below method will be called when a swipe gesture occurs either swipeUp or swipeDown.
When the method receives a swipeUp gesture it scrolls the last currently visible row in the tableview to the top
When the method receives a swipeDown it scrolls the first currently visible row to the bottom

-(void)motion:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

```
if (sender.direction==UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp) {
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows objectAtIndex:[self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows count]-1]  atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}else if(sender.direction==UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)
{
   [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows objectAtIndex:0 ] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

//let myView be the view from which you want to scroll your tableview(myTableview)

//now add the following lines in your viewdidload method

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipegesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]init];
swipegesture =[myTableview.gestureRecognizers objectAtIndex:1];
[myView addGestureRecognizer:swipegesture];
```